# jquery form submitting

Tags: php, jquery

index.php

```
<form method="post" action="read.php">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="" /></p>
    <p><button type="submit">Okay</button></p>
</form>
```

i'd like to send name value to read.php without refreshing the page. i wanna use jquery. but how?

Edit:
i want to make this job without refreshing the page. well, i tried every examples, and they sent me to read.php after pressing the okay button. i dont wanna go to read.php.

edit2: lol, we can't send a value to another page without refreshing the page :) such a shame for us. lol

Answer (score 1):

[Download jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) and include it in your application.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){     
   jQuery('form').live('submit',function(event) {
      $.ajax({
          url: $(this).attr('action'),
          type: 'POST',
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          success: function( response ) {
              alert(response);
          }
      });
      return false;
  });
 });
```

Comment: yes. `url: $(this).attr('action')` part of above code will take care of your action script in your submitted form tag. So in your case it will be `read.php`. You can hard code it like this: `url: read.php`

Answer (score 0):

Use the ajax forms plugin. http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and look for the example "Save some data to the server and notify the user once it's complete."

Answer (score 0):

Use [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
$.post(
    'read.php',
    {
        'name': $('input[name="name"]').val()
    }
);
```

Comment: You should `return false;` in your `submit()` handler function.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function(){ 
           $("#ajax-form").submit(function(){ 
               $.post( 
                   "/read.php", 
                   $("#ajax-form").serialize(),  
              ); 
           }); 
      });

and make the form with the id ajax-form